# Control + Shift + Z key combination not working for browsers

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, google-chrome, firefox

I tried the keys combination <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on my  MacBook Pro (Ventura 13.2.1), but this is not getting seen for the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

I tested at https://en.key-test.ru/  that I am not able to press the combination in the order <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (a different order may work). Also the keys <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> do not work with combination of <kbd>^ Control</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>for the web applications.

For application other than web, the combination is working fine.

This works fine for Windows and on a MacBook Air (Monterey), but not on a MacBook Pro (Ventura)

- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> works fine
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> works fine
- <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is not working

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. 
I am able to use control + shift key with "z,s,d" keys but not with "c" key, it is not still working

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue.  *Safe Mode is a diagnostic mode;* boot normally and the issue will reappear.  This means some third party app or driver is the cause and not macOS.  It's time to do some investigative work.